# Multiple processes listening to Intel RealSense input running at the same time?

Tags: intel, realsense

I plan to buy a RealSense, so I don't have it yet to test and hack around.

My question is simple : I want to run some software in foreground that uses RealSense as input, but I also want to run at the same time some process in the background that also listens to RealSense input and triggers an action when some input is detected.

Is that possible? Or is the RealSense SDK limiting to one listening process (and/or instance)?

Comment: You'll probably get an answer quicker on the RealSense developers forum: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/realsense Why not create a single instance only WebSockets based server that handles all interaction with the camera and  have all your other client apps talk to it?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do! Well, I don't control one of the software I want to use... Basically, I want to use some existing software in foreground, and one app I'll write myself in background. So it's not only "My" applications, otherwise it wouldn't be a problem. :)

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to whether you want multiple programs to use the same raw data stream from the RealSense camera or whether you want multiple programs to be able to send input (say different gestures) to more than one realsense apps thru the camera interface at the same time?

Comment: Multiple programs to use the same raw data stream from the RealSense camera *at the same time*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple programs can use the same raw data stream - the first one to take control of the camera gets to control the settings but others can use the stream. Be sure to install the Depth Camera Manager (DCM) that acts as the single voice to the camera.

Comment: Indeed, I received a RealSense today and I confirm it works. Thanks!